# Why dont i have to instantiate an object of the NumberFormat class?

Tags: java, static

I was working with the `NumberFormat` class. I thought I had to do something like:

```
NumberFormat currency= new NumberFormat();
currency.getCurrencyInstance();
```

But this is not the case. It is even impossible to do so?
Instead i had to do the following:

```
NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

Why is this, what is the difference?

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: Sorry, the language is java

Comment: You do, unless you think the only way to instantiate anything is with `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `NumberFormat` instances are reused. In fact you have only one `NumberFormat` object for a given locale. This is done as a performance optimization. You can take a look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/NumberFormat.java#NumberFormat.getInstance%28java.util.Locale%2Cint%29) for more deep understanding.

If you call the `getCurrencyInstance` multiple times, you will get the same object each time:

```
currency1 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
currency2 = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.println("The same object? : " + (currency1 == currency2)); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot instantiate the `NumberFormat` object using `new` because it is an `abstract` class. Abstract classes are meant solely for inheritance, you cannot instantiate an object of an `abstract` class.

Quoting it from the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

> NumberFormat is the **abstract base class** for all number formats. This class provides the interface for formatting and parsing numbers. NumberFormat also provides methods for determining which locales have number formats, and what their names are.

To get the concrete format class object based on your locale, you need to use a factory class methods (which is a design pattern).

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);//French Locale
```

or

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();//Gives you current locale's concrete class object
```

Also, note that NumberFormat is not thread safe. So, always create a separate format instances(which can be synchronised externally in case of concurrency).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you run the code below you will find that on most JVMs it fails.

```
`assert NumberFormat.getInstance() == NumberFormat.getInstance();`
```

The trick is that if you are only parsing a few numbers, creating a new NumberFormat object is not a big deal, so that is the best pattern to use for almost all new Java programmers.

BUT, and this is a big but, if you are doing any sort of large scale parsing project, you will want to reuse your NumberFormat classes for efficiencies sake.

As NumberFormat is not thread safe, the easiest way to do this is to have a util class that stores the NumberFormat in a ThreadLocal variable.